# Gini coefficient, ineq package in R and integer overflow

Tags: r, integer-overflow

I want to calculate the Gini coefficient for each column in a `2090 x 25` dataframe. I am using the Gini function in the ineq package and the following code:

```
gini <- sapply(mydata, function(x) ineq(x,type="Gini")).
```

This produces results that look valid but also the following warning message:

Warning messages:

```
1: In n * sum(x) : NAs produced by integer overflow
2: In sum(x * 1:n) : Integer overflow - use sum(as.numeric(.))
3: In n * sum(x) : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

To overcome the integer overflow I converted the dataframe to a matrix `(mymatrix <- as.matrix(mydf))` but then the results were all zeros or NAs. I think this is because ineq package requires a vector and matrix is not a vector.

My questions are:

- how can I convert integer columns to numeric and retain a vector class?
- are there any other options to work around the integer overflow problem?

Thanks

Nerida

Comment: Can you do `str(mydata)` and then `dput` a subset of your data to replicate this error

Comment: When you're sapplying, each column is converted to a vector.

Answer (score 1):

In absence of more info, my guess would be you might prefer

```
sapply(1:25, function(x) ineq(as.numeric(mydata[,x],type='Gini')) )
```

Edit: as @James and @Roman pointed out, `sapply` will grab each element of a dataframe in turn, so

```
sapply(mydata,function(x) ineq(as.numeric(x),type='Gini') )
```

should produce the same result.

Comment: @user2446647 If it's good enough, please check the answer so it'll be marked as accepted.  Thanks!