# How to resample gini coefficient when there is an integer overflow?

Tags: r, integer-overflow, resampling

I want to calculate confidence intervals for a gini coefficient and I tried to 
apply the boot() function shown below for that purpose ([as suggested here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21868/gini-coefficient-and-error-bounds)):

```
library(reldist) # just for the gini() function
library(boot) # for the boot() function
x <- c(1,2,2,3,4,99)
gini(x)
y <- boot(x, gini, 500)
quantile(y$t, probs=c(0.025, 0.975))
```

It works perfectly fine in this example. But when I try to apply it on my actual data I receive a warning ( "In sum(weights) : integer overflow - use sum(as.numeric(.))" ) and the function doesn't work. Instead of the quantile I receive an error:
" Error in quantile.default(y2$t, probs = c(0.025, 0.975)) : missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE"

I am not entirely sure whether the integer overflow warning and this error are related but I guess so. I read several posts on integer overflow ([for example this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804779/what-is-integer-overflow-in-r-and-how-can-it-happen)) and downloaded the Rmpfr package ([as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804779/what-is-integer-overflow-in-r-and-how-can-it-happen)). Without a very clear understanding of what's happening I  tried to enter x as a mpfr object but it didn't work.  Also, my variable is numeric so simply using as.numeric conversion ([as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890686/gini-coefficient-ineq-package-in-r-and-integer-overflow)) is also not the solution.

Is there an alternative way to calculate error bounds for gini, or a solution to this problem?

Comment: Maybe set `na.rm=TRUE` in the call to `quantile` if that is an appropriate step in your analysis, which I guess it would be. You may be able to investigate more into `gini` to understand why it generates the NA to begin with.

Comment: Setting na.rm=TRUE  did not solve the problem. I just receives NAs for both quantiles.

Comment: So what is in `y` in this case? Could you post your data or data that replicates this problem?

Comment: Interestingly, when I produce a small subset of my data the function works perfectly fine. I did it over and over again but couldn't replicate the problem. It looks like the problem persists only if  only if I choose a very large  sample or try to apply the function to the entire data set, which has around 130000 cases! I am happy to post a dropbox link to share the variable if it's OK to do so.